# How to force download xml file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, file

Given this solution on how to create XML format to my data ([Convert JavaScript object (array) to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311562/convert-javascript-object-array-to-xml/52311711#52311711?newreg=8d2eabe126fb443dbbb434372683dc80))

I need now a way to make auto download this into a .xml file this is my code:

```
toXml = (data) => {
    return data.reduce((result, el) => {
        if (el.title && el.author)
            return result + `<BookData><title>${el.title}</title><author>${el.author}</author></BookData>\n`
        if (el.title && !el.author)
            return result + `<BookData><title>${el.title}</title></BookData>\n`
        if (!el.title && el.author)
            return result + `<BookData><author>${el.author}</author></BookData>\n`
    }, '')
}

if (type == 2)
{
    let data = this.toXml(arrayData);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Where I pass the data to create my XML?

What should I code instead of `console.log(data);` so I can get the downloaded .xml file?

Edit: Answered in 
[How to create and download an XML file on the fly using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143504/how-to-create-and-download-an-xml-file-on-the-fly-using-javascript)

Comment: You could use something like [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) in JavaScript in order to create a client-side URL object from that data, and then use any of the [multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link) to download the blob. Slightly more inconsistent than what it might be desirable, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never. This code downloads an XML file using javascript:

```
 var pseudoelement = document.createElement("a");

  var filename = "example.xml";
  var pseudoelement = document.createElement("a");
  var blob = new Blob([toXml ], { type: "text/plain" });

  pseudoelement.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  pseudoelement.setAttribute("download", filename);

  pseudoelement.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/plain", pseudoelement.download, pseudoelement.href].join(":");
  pseudoelement.draggable = true;
  pseudoelement.classList.add("dragout");

  pseudoelement.click();
```

thank_for_this